# how to pass a javascript variable to another php file

Tags: javascript, php, html

I have a javascript file which contains an array of `variable-array[]` and I want to pass this variable to another php file using `post(data=array)`. So that I can get the `$_POST['data']` inside the php file.How can I do it?

Comment: use $.post  http://api.jquery.com/jquery.post/

Comment: If you already have a form you can also set a hidden value in the form and then submit it all with javascript.

Answer (score 0):

You can use an Ajax POST to the php script to send data:

```
$.ajax({
  type: "POST", //http method
  url: url, //url to php file
  data: data, //array or json object
  success: success, //callback
});
```

In PHP you will need to get the data from the `$_POST` array.

Comment: The code above is working with jQuery, so its working via JavaScript on you clients browser.

Answer (score 0):

```
var val1 = 'test1';
var val2 = 'test2';
$.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url: 'yourfile.php',
    data: { data: [text1: val1, text2: val2] },
    success: function(response) {
    console.log(response);
    }
});
```

Comment: I cannot use$.ajax({{); directly. The error message is unsolved function
function input() {
        $.ajax ({
            url: 'update_service.php',
            type : 'POST',
            data : {val : h},
            success: function( result ) {
                alert( result );
            }
        });
    }

Answer (score 0):

You can't directly do that, since JavaScript runs on the client-side and PHP gets executed on the server-side. You would  need to execute the JavaScript first and then send the result to the server via a FORM or AJAX call.

PHP

```
$parameter = "this is a php variable";
echo "var myval = foo(" . parameter . ");";
```

javascript

```
var myval = foo("this is a php variable"); // generated by PHP

$.ajax({
  type: 'POST',
  url: 'yourphpfile.php',
  data: {'variable': myval},
});
```

Receiving PHP (yourphpfile.php)

```
 $myval = $_POST['variable'];
  //do something!
```

Comment: put $.ajax({}); inside a function inside javascript?

Comment: Where ever your need for ajax! you may write down ajax function in function or wherever you need.